# XSL: how can I generate a regex pattern on demand?

Tags: regex, xslt

I would like to generate a regex pattern on demand, somehow I fail. Maybe someone knows why and can help.

What I would like to achieve is having elements which define text to be (as example) marked bold in the output

Source xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <strong>Empire</strong>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <strong>your</strong>
        <strong>heart</strong>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table border="1">
                    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:call-template name="addBold">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="title" />
<xsl:with-param name="replace"><xsl:variable name="temp"><xsl:for-each select="strong">|<xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:for-each></xsl:variable>(<xsl:value-of select='substring-after($temp,"|")' />)</xsl:with-param>
                                </xsl:call-template>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="artist" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="addBold">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:param name="replace" />
    <xsl:analyze-string select="$text" regex="$replace">

        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <b><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)" /></b>
        </xsl:matching-substring>

        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>

    </xsl:analyze-string>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The `$replace` parameter would then contain eg. `(your|heart)`. But it's never matched in the `xsl:analyze-string` element.

If I replace `$replace` with hard coded "`(your|heart)`" it always works fine..

Is there an important thing I missed? like I cannot use a variable/parameter as pattern? or do I need to make sure it's formatted properly? which I did in the call-template paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an attribute value template i.e. `<xsl:analyze-string select="$text" regex="{$replace}">` for the `regex` attribute.

Comment: thanks a lot… 

I had figured out the same but then got another weird error

but then I did the whole thing again on a new "installation" and as you suggested with the additional { and } everything worked just smoothly...

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you are using a variable reference inside of the `regex` attribute of `xsl:analyze-string`. The regex attribute accepts a string as input.

It is currently evaluating the value of `regex` as the string literal "$replace" (which won't match anything).

**You need to use an [attribute value template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#dt-attribute-value-template) in order for it to evaluate the variable and use it's string value for `regex`:**

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="$text" regex="{$replace}">
```

Also, you could simplify the expression creating the REGEX for the replace param with the following:

```
<xsl:with-param name="replace" select="concat('(',string-join(strong,'|'),')')">
```